# why "extra characters after command" error shown for the sed command line shown?

Tags: sql, linux, shell, sed

I have given the command line as shown below,

command:

```
sed '/dump 0 $2 $3 $4 $5/dump 1 $2 $3 $4 $5/g' base_file.properties
```

error showing

> sed: -e expression #1, char 22: extra characters after command

while putting "s" option as

```
 sed 's/dump 0 $2 $3 $4 $5/dump 1 $2 $3 $4 $5/g' base_file.properties
```

error is showing as

> sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that some of the variables are expanding to values that contain a `/`.  Use a different delimiter that isn't contained in any of the variables, e.g.

```
sed 's@dump 0 $2 $3 $4 $5@dump 1 $2 $3 $4 $5@g' base_file.properties
```

(Your first command isn't a valid `sed` expression.)