# Using sed in terminal to replace text in file

Tags: sed, terminal, command

I have this text in this file:

**test.php**

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'original',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost'
    ),
  ),
);
```

In terminal run this line to replace 'original' with 'new'

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' test.php
```

UPDATE: The error message is:

> sed: 1: "test.php": undefined label 'est.php'

What is the problem?

UPDATE 2:

If I just run: ( I removed '-i')

```
sed 's/original/new/g' test.php
```

I see the file text modified in the terminal. But then the file is not saved.

Comment: It's rather unlikely to get the error message you've mentioned by issuing `sed -i 's/original/new/g' test.php`.  What command did you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why "extra characters after command" error shown for the sed command line shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924737/why-extra-characters-after-command-error-shown-for-the-sed-command-line-shown)

Comment: I found that problem is the '-i'. If I run just 'sed 's/original/new/g' test.php' (I removed '-i') it works but the file is not saved.

Comment: BTW: why the downvote...?

Comment: @devnull I just copy/paste the commands. Pretty sure.

Comment: @devnull Sorry you were right. The error message is this one: sed: 1: "test.php": undefined label 'est.php'

Comment: @chefnelone You haven't still showed the actual problem code.  It seems that the linked duplicate question would resolve the issue you're facing.

Comment: @devnull I updated my question with the right error message. I tried using other delimiter as said in the other question link but it didn't  work.

Comment: @chefnelone Are the pattern & replacement strings variables?

Comment: @devnull no, they are just text

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On BSDish platforms (including Mac OSX), the `-i` option requires an argument.

```
sed -i '' 's/original/new/g' test.php
```

Notice the empty argument `''`.

Comment: If you don't ever expect multiple matches on a single line, the `/g` flag is superfluous.

Comment: Related: options for doing `sed -i` portably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux